# sql how to assign the same ID for the same group

Tags: sql

I have a dataset as this:

```
ID         SESSION         DATE                              
1             A           2021/1/1       
1             A           2021/1/2      
1             B           2021/1/3       
1.            B           2021/1/4      
1             A           2021/1/5       
1             A           2021/1/6
```

So what I want to create is the **GROUP** column which assigns the same row number for where ID column AND SESSION column is the same as below:

```
    ID         SESSION         DATE         GROUP                       
     1             A           2021/1/1        1
     1             A           2021/1/2        1
     1             B           2021/1/3        2
     1             B           2021/1/4        2
     1             A           2021/1/5        3
     1             A           2021/1/6        3
```

Does anyone know how to do this in SQL in an efficient way because I have about 5 billion rows? Thank you in advance!

Comment: please tag just one RDBMS

Comment: You need to explain the logic I didn't get it , please give an example at least about 4 rows what will be the calculation

Comment: The key search phrase here is "gaps and islands".

Comment: @DolevDublon I have just edited my question again! so what I want is to create the column GROUP in the second table, which is the sequenceID when column ID and column SESSION are the same. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: The 5th and 6th rows have the same `ID` and `SESSION` as the first two rows. Why are they not in the 1st `GROUP`?

Comment: We need to know your [(R)DBMS, please tag this information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a kind of *gaps and islands* problem, you can create your groupings by counting when the session changes using *lag*, like so:

```
select Id, Session, Date,  
  Sum(case when session = prevSession then 0 else 1 end) over(partition by Id order by date) "Group"
from (
  select *, 
    Lag(Session) over(partition by Id order by date) prevSession
  from t
)t;
```

Example [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_5HXu9hq) using MySql but this is ansi SQL that should work in most DBMS.

Comment: [Window functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function_(SQL)) like `over(partition by .. order by ..)` were introduced with ANSI SQL:2003, still not sure if DBMS used for question supports them.

Comment: The question is Tagged `ansi sql` and it's not unreasonable to assume it's not 20+ years old.

Comment: @Stu, thanks so much! This really helps me solve the problem!